# Did Spock have a good relationship with his mother's family on Earth?

Tags: star-trek, spock

I would like to know if there is anything in Star Trek canon that says that Spock had a good relationship with his mother's family on Earth. For example, would he from time-to-time visit with the Grayson family when he was not on duty or on vacation?

I have searched a good number of Star Trek websites and Wikipedia for any insights on his relationship with his Earth relatives, but have found very little information on it. Perhaps there is something written about this relationship in a Star Trek novel?

Did Spock have a good relationship with his mother's family on Earth?

Comment: It's not fully canon but the novel "Sarek" is probably the most respectful dramatization of that period of Spock's life and should be canon in my opinion.   As I recall the flashbacks were based on Amanda's diary.  I don't recall anything about family but if it is anywhere it would be in this novel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Main Canon

There's no canon (TV or Film) mention of Spock's human family other than a fleeting statement in Discovery about a phrase that [Amanda's mother](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Unnamed_Humans_(23rd_century)#Amanda.27s_mother_001) used to use. It's impossible, therefore, to determine what Spock's relationship with his Earth family was although we do at least know that they were alive during his lifetime. It's logical to assume that he would have learned about them and possibly contacted them, but beyond that we really can't go any further.

---

### EU

In the Extended Universe of novels and stories there are a number of references to his family on Earth.

In [*Strange New Worlds: Family Matters*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Family_Matters_(TOS_short_story)) Spock travels to Earth at the request of his aunt (Amanda's sister). His cousin was in a traffic accident and is comatose. We learn that his relationship with his human family is almost non-existent. He attended his grandmother's funeral and that's it.

> “I—I almost didn’t recognize you; I haven’t seen you since you were a boy. Elizabeth wasn’t even born yet. How old were you then? About fifteen?”
>
> He calculated as he turned up his collar; then he slid his hands back into his coat pockets. Wasn’t she going to ask him inside?
>
> “Twenty-eight point seven two Terran standard years, Aunt Kathleen.” His breath formed a white cloud between them. She started as though suddenly aware of the below-freezing temperature.
>
> ....
>
> No wonder she had transferred her hate to Spock. Physically, he bore little resemblance to his mother. Because he had already undergone the Kahs-wan coming-of-age ceremony by his first visit to Earth and Grandmother Grayson’s funeral, Kathleen had never seen the child-Spock laugh, cry, or play as a human child would. And now, he could not permit himself to demonstrate the emotionalism that would prove his mother’s heritage.

By the the end of the story he's on friendlier terms.

---

On another occasion ([*TOS: Ishmael*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmael_(Star_Trek))) Spock travels back in time to the 1800s where he passes himself off as a human and spends time with his ancestors, presumably Amanda Grayson's great-great-(great?)grandfather and great-great-(great?)grandmother.

Comment: And Amanda's great-great-great grandmother.  Amanda owns a locket once owned by Biddy Cloom.  Aaron Stempel is Amanda's how many ever time great grandfather, and Biddy Cloom is the woman that Aaron marries.  Biddy already owned the locket by the time she meets Aaron.  Spock meets both of them and spends time with both before recovering his memory.

Comment: @JRE - I've not read this book for many many years. I've updated the post accordingly.

Comment: @Valorum  As someone interested in genealogy, I can tell you that it can be hard to estimate the number of generations of  family born within a time span.  To guote Star Trek examples,Keiko O'Brien's mother was probably about 60 years older than her, and in "The Neutral Zone" Clare Raymond died about 370 years earlier but Troi finds that her great great great great great grandson is alive and not looking a century old according to his photo.